# To Hide Empty Column in Jspdf-Autotable

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

preparing summary report in jspdf-autotable.How do i hide empty column and header

```
const headers=[["PRICE","CARRIER","CUSTOMER ID","QUANTITY"]] 
const data = this.state.data.map(elt=> [elt.price,elt.carrier,elt.from,elt.duration]); 

let content = {
  startY: 50,
  head: headers,
  body: data,

};

doc.text(title, marginLeft, 40);
doc.autoTable(content);
```

I expect output to hide customerid in pdf because it does not have any data in table[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to filter those values out before passing them to the plugin.